# Use Regex to Search File Extension in Directory

Tags: vb.net

why the following code get the .docx file? I have search to use regex to search specific file extensions.  I need to have multiple file extensions to search.  However I haven't find it. I know I can use loop to go through, but I am think whether it is fast way to get it. Would you provide a link to me or example.  Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(RootPath)
    Dim files As FileInfo() = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find multiple extensions in a directory is with a combination of a pattern list and LINQ:

```
    Dim CurrentDir = New IO.DirectoryInfo(RootPath)
    Dim patterns = {".docx", ".xlsx", ".ini"}
    Dim files = (From f In CurrentDir.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                   Where patterns.Contains(f.Extension)
                   Select f)
```

One advantage of this is all the matching is literal with no wildcard matching affecting the results.

Comment: I am using vb.net. Would you tell me how to do it?

Comment: The code in my answer is in VB.net.  Basically just plug it in.  `files` will return a collection of `FileSystemInfo` for all the files matching the patterns in `patterns` that are in `RootPath`  I changed the `DirectoryInfo` object to `CurrentDir` instead of `dirInfo`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the MSDN documentation for [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx), this seems to be by design for some reason. This will answer the question "Why is this happening?"

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern (for example, "*.txt"), the matching behavior varies depending on the length of the specified file extension. **A searchPattern with a file extension of exactly three characters returns files with an extension of three or more characters**, where the first three characters match the file extension specified in the searchPattern. A searchPattern with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters returns only files with extensions of exactly that length that match the file extension specified in the searchPattern. When using the question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that match the specified file extension. **For example, given two files in a directory, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", a search pattern of "file?.txt" returns only the first file, while a search pattern of "file*.txt" returns both files**.

It seems like you may have an unstated question here, which is what can you do to get only the .doc files without getting .docx files. Let me know if that is your next question, and I can help answer that.